# Is it possible to narrow only if needed?

Tags: c++, guideline-support-library

Suppose I had the following code where `bar` is defined in another library:

```
void bar(int x);  /* this declaration comes from some included header file */

void foo(long long y)
{
    return bar(y);
}
```

To make failures detectable, the GSL instructs me to use `gsl::narrow` as follows:

```
void bar(int x);  /* this declaration comes from some included header file */

void foo(long long y)
{
    return bar(narrow<int>(y));
}
```

My problem is that, suppose I knew `void bar(long long x);` is likely to appear in future releases of the library, the first version will automatically switch to use it (by deduction rules), whereas the second version will not. Is there any way to detect narrowing failures while `void bar(long long x);` is not available, and switch to just calling it when released?

I tried:

- `bar(narrow(y));`, but the template argument of narrow could not be deduced.
- `bar(superint{y})`, where superint is a `struct {long long x;}` with overloaded typecast operator for both `long long` and `int`, the latter with narrow check. This is my best idea so far as it gives an `ambiguous call` compile-time error when `void bar(long long x);` is added, making us aware of the places to update our codebase when time is right. It doesn't look like something you would put in the GSL though, so I am not quite satified..

**UPDATE**

There are plenty of good answers, but they all have to be implemented per-function rather than per-argument. Ideally the solution should look something like the GSL where you just do something to the arguments that are in risk of narrowing. The visitor pattern could be useful here, where we would just have to rewrite `quz(xi,yi,z,w)` to `superint_visit(quz, superint{xi},superint{xi},z,w);` assuming xi and yi were the integer arguments in risk of narrowing. Something like:

```
struct superint
{
    long long x;
    operator long long() { return x; }
    operator int()       { return narrow<int>(x); }
};

template <typename F, typename... Args>
auto superint_visit(F func, Args&&... args)
{
    /* if replacing 'superint' with 'long long' in Args 
       gives a function that is declared, call that function 
       (using static_cast<long long> on all 'superint' args 
       to resolve ambiguity). Otherwise, use static_cast<int> 
       on all 'superint' args and call that function instead. */
}
```

All the above could live in `gsl` namespace, and I would just have to write my function as:

```
void foo(long long x)
{
    return superint_visit(bar, superint{x});
}
```

Even though I accepted an answer here, I'll still like to hear from anyone who can make the above happen!

Comment: how about making bar a template ? This way you just can call bar(y) and make all size related decision in bar implementation. To its clients the bar should be capable of dealing with whatever integer type. I think that is what you are basically looking for.

Comment: Not my library @StPiere

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can leverage the fact that overload resolution favours a perfect argument type match for a non-template function over a function template:

```
#include <iostream>

// (A)
void bar(int y) { std::cout << "bar(int)\n"; }
// (B)
//void bar(long long) { std::cout << "bar(long long)\n"; }

// (C)
template <typename T>
void bar(T) = delete;

// (C.SP1)
template<>
void bar<long long>(long long y) { bar(narrow<int>(y)); }

int main() {
    long long a = 12LL;
    bar(a); // bar(int)
            // bar(long long) if `bar(long long)` above is available.
}
```

If `void bar(long long);` is not available, any call to `bar(a)` for an argument `a` of type `long long` will favour the non-narrowing function template overload (C), whose primary template has been deleted to only allow invocation when `T` is exactly `long long` (no conversions) through the specialization (C.SP1). Once `void bar(long long);` at (B) becomes available, it will be chosen as a better viable candidate by overload resolution than that of the function template candidate.

If you are worried that introducing an additional `bar` overload (the function template above) may break overload resolution of `bar` when compiling the library itself, you could add a public wrapper for `bar` and place the overload resolution delegation above in the TU where the wrapper is defined, applying internal linkage for the added `bar` overload by declaring it in an unnamed namespace. E.g.:

```
// foo.h
#pragma once
void foo(long long y);

// foo.cpp
#include "foo.h"
#include "gsl/gsl_narrow"
#include "the_lib/bar.h"

namespace {

template <typename T>
void bar(T) = delete;

template<>
void bar<long long>(long long y) { bar(narrow<int>(y)); }

}  // namespace

void foo(long long y) {
    bar(y);
}
```

Comment: Nice but this could break overload resolution in the library itself depending on when you present your template overload to the compiler.

Comment: @Bathsheba yes, good point. I supposed you could add a public wrapper for `bar` and place the overload resolution delegation above in the TU where the wrapper is defined, applying internal linkage for the added `bar` overload.

Answer (score 2):

You don't own `bar`? No problem. It's a matter of getting the `decltype` for `x`. This you can do by getting the `decltype` for the whole function, and writing a `template` to recover the argument type:

```
template <typename>
struct argType;

template <typename R, typename A>
struct argType<R(A)>
{
    using type = A;
};

void foo(long long y)
{     
    bar(narrow<typename argType<decltype(bar)>::type>(y));
}
```

Comment: nice solution. but needing to write this at every single call to bar is not so readable. maybe adding one level of indirection with custom function would be still more appropriate

Comment: @StPiere You can shorten it by a typedef or a using on the type `typename argType<decltype(bar)>::type`

Comment: I wonder if there is a nice solution already in std, like [std::result_of](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/result_of) which may give type of return value of _bar_.

Comment: @Bashheba,  of course, that would be nicer. One would just need to know at every invocation to what type the narrow cast should cast. i personaly find this odd from the design perspective, but that was not the question topic. but still, nice.

Comment: @ŁukaszŚlusarczyk: It's not the return type you're after but the type of the first parameter. My solution could be improved with further specialisations; perhaps even a variadic template to extract the first argument type from a function with more than one parameter. *Reflection* will be able to do this once available - methinks it will operate on similar lines to my answer? This ain't my pattern - nicked it from a smart author of some book or other - I'm just a humble mathematician.

Comment: @Jarod42: "Suppose I had the following code where bar is defined in another library:" - in other words you don't *want* to introduce other overloads.

Comment: I meant, if library has also `void bar(char)`, you cannot take type of `bar`, and when `void bar(long long)` would be added, code would fail to compile too (that allow to remove the workaround :)). but if `void bar(long long)` replaces `void bar(int)`, it would compile though (letting the work-around in place).

Comment: @Bathsheba, agree. I meant I'd like to have something like std::result_of to get arguments. I finally found what I wanted in boost in callable_traits - see my answer. It does the same as your code, but without need to write it on your own.

Answer (score 1):

Getting type of first argument may be done using [boost::callable_traits::args](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/libs/callable_traits/doc/html/callable_traits/reference.html#callable_traits.reference.ref_args) which will give you a
[std::tuple](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple) with types of all arguments, which then may be used to get type of first argument using [std::tuple_element](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tuple_element)

```
#include <boost/callable_traits/args.hpp>

void bar(int y);

void foo(long long y)
{
  bar(narrow<std::tuple_element<0, boost::callable_traits::args_t<decltype(bar)>>::type>(y));
}
```

Comment: Which comes with the same limitation as [pointed out by @Jarod32](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63521155/is-it-possible-to-narrow-only-if-needed/63521564#comment112324770_63521421) in a comment to another answer: there shall be no other overloads of `bar` in the library, and the future `bar(long long)` overload must replace the `bar(int)` one.

Comment: Nice. That comes out elegantly using Boost. +1.

Answer (score 0):

There are really nice creative solutions already posted to the question. But they all have the problem of depending of the library implementation - for ex. if bar overloads are present then client code doesnt compile.

From my point of view, what the client of bar really wants in this case is:

"I'd like to use the bar accepting one specific integral parameter, unrelated if other overloads exist".

The library-independent non-intrinsic straight forward way is also the simplest one - a thin bar wrapper accpeting an integral parameter. This way it's undependent of any library implementation details:

```
void bar(int x);  /* this declaration comes from some included header file */

template <typename T, typename = std::enable_if_v<std::is_integral_v<T>>>
inline void mybar(T x)
{
     // express directly which bar overload you want to use here 
     bar(narrow<int>(x));  // <- the only place you need to ajudst if bar interface changes, btw. use the overload from bar which you really want
}

void foo(long long y)
{
    return mybar(y);  // use mybar instead of bar within your code
}
```

If bar overloads for int and long are present, then you could differentiate between those two by simply specializing your own mybar.

If bar library interface changes, the client should addapt and recompile anyway. What you really want here is to keep those changes central.

In my opinion, you have already answered your own question, more or less.